# Match number in range followed by 1-3 letters

Tags: regex, oracle, business-intelligence

I have to match numbers between 1 and 33689 and after this it should come A, AB or ABC.

I have now %1, `^[0-9\.]{0,5}.*[A-z]+$` and I am working with Oracle Business Intelligence. So, it is not a direct database query. With MySQL I have made with `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,5}([^[:digit:]]|$)` and I have made an order by with

```
regexp_substr(replace(number,'.',''),'^(\d+)',1,1,NULL,1)
```

and it works very well.

But I cannot make it 1 to 1 in the Oracle Business Intelligence.

Comment: It is unclear if you wish to match this range exactly (regex isn't good at this, but it's possible) or if the number of digits is a sufficient approximation, after which you can do further validation. Since Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) is probably not that widespread among regex users, perhaps you could clarify what parts of your regex that OBIEE does not support.

Comment: Yes, I wan to match the range ( I am aware it is not possible to get it).

Comment: Actually I have to match A, AA or AAA.

Comment: You're dealing with two domains here, and you don't have a working solution until you've both created the proper regex *and* managed a way to correctly call it. Your question is being downvoted and voted closed because you're not making it obvious if you're stuck with the regex itself or calling it. Clarify your progress on making `regexp_substr` work for *any* regex, otherwise people's efforts on producing the right one are hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems appear to be related to Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) more than regexes. The basic regex of 1-5 digits followed by 1-3 letters is achieved with `^[0-9]{1-5}[A-Z]{1-3}$`. If you want to avoid prefix zeros and [match a specific numeric range](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html), the following matches the range 0-33689:

```
0|[1-9][0-9]{0-3}|[12][0-9]{4}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|336[0-7][0-9]|3368[0-9]
```

And 1-3 'A's is quite trivially `A{1-3}`.

As the blog post [Regular Expressions in OBIEE](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2009/12/regular-expressions-in-obiee/) suggests,

> The only issue here is that OBIEE does not support regular expressions in its SQL language, so I have to use the EVALAUTE command to pass Oracle's regular expression syntax back through to the database.

It continues to give an example of this:

```
Evaluate('regexp_substr(%1,''regex_goes_here''), "FIELD_NAME")'
```

Since you didn't provide the context in which you're executing this regular expression, it is entirely unclear if you're failing to describe a proper pattern, if *Oracle's regular expression syntax* lacks some of the features you're using (I can't claim to know this dialect), but e.g. named character groups (`\d`) and character ranges (`{1-3}`) are not supported by all regex engines.

Perhaps your problem lies with calling `Evaluate` or `regexp_substr`.

Comment: This is correct. I am using the evaluate of course. It looks like evaluate('REGEXP_INSTR(?:0?\d{1,4}|[1-3]{0,2}[1-5][1-8]\d)[I]{1,3}+$'')',"TelDetails"."SignNumber") = '0'

Comment: So, if I use your code for the range, I also get letters. I also get '00A05A' or '00-01'.It is just a query. It looks like evaluate('REGEXP_INSTR(%1, ''^[1-9][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|336[0-7][0-9]|3368[0-9[I]{1-3}+$'')',"TelDetails"."SignNumber")

Comment: @Myvie: The regular expression `^a|b$` means "Match either `a` at the beginning of the string, or `b` at the end of the string." This is because `^` and `$` bind tighter than `|`. So you will want to write `^(a|b)c$` for appropriate sub-regexes `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

match any 5-digit that is followed by A AA or AAA

```
/^[0-9]{5}(A?){3}$/
```

and parse any found match to integer

```
Pseudocode:
var tmp = parse_to_int(match)
```

compare the result with 33689

```
Pseudocode:
if(tmp <= 33689)
    {
        //proceed as you wish
    }
```

Comment: Tks Tolar. The issue are not the letters but the range. I still do not know exactly how the OBIEE works. I am working since a month with. However. I am quite sure the problem is the regex as it does not work exactly like MySQL. Now it looks like 'REGEXP_INSTR(%1, ''^[1-9][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|336[0-7][0-9]|3368[0-9[A]{1-3}+$''

Comment: The regex you post here in the comment has alot of matches without the ending A-letters.

And I am not sure about the context that you are using this but the range can be tested after finding a candidate-match, that's what my answer was about, besically:

candidate = 'REGEXP_INSTR(%1, ''/^[0-9]{5}(A?){3}$/'';
s_number = regex_match(candidate, '/^[0-9]{5}$/');
i_number = parse_int(s_number);
if(i_number <= 33689)
    {
       //you fuond what you want now yuo can do with it what you want
    }

Comment: The end does not have to be exactly with A. It can have some other signs after that but they do not matter for me. This is the reason why I asked just for the main part. Sorry about that. I want to retrieve from 0 until 33689. In the database it can be with 33689A or 33.689A or 33.689A and this is my main problem. It about some old data. Some are from archives with more than 200 years. As we did not have a codes in the past I am trying to find out which are already in the system and wich not. Is this better now? I will improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for the range ending in A, AA or AAA:

[`^(?:336[0-8][0-9]|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-9])A{1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZxIjAf/1/)

Comment: just like  evaluate('REGEXP_INSTR(%1, ''^(?:336[0-8][0-9]|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-9])[A]{1,3}+$'')'  ???

Comment: I have got just 6 results. They are like expected (e.g. 20884A) but it should be some thousand more. So, something still must be missing... I have now   evaluate('REGEXP_INSTR(%1, ''^(?:336[0-8][0-9]|33[0-5][0-9]{2}|3[0-2][0-9]{3}|[12][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-9])[A]{1,3}+$'')'

Comment: Still the same 6 results....Sorry, some examples. it should come 123A or 30.111 AA. Actually the result should come like "30111AA". But at first I would like to match the string. Of course I am still trying to improve to put the . or blanks away.

Comment: The regex matches from the `^` begin of the string until the `$` end of the string. The values you are trying to match like `123A`, are they inside a string or exactly those values? You could try it without `^$`. The regex does not match `30.111 AA` because there is a space and a dot in it.

Comment: yes, sure. I still have to improve the regex to ignore the dot and the spaces. 123A are inside a string. I have data from old systems as well. Some people put 123A in the past but some just put 123 A and some 1.236A or 1236 A.

Comment: @Myvie What you could do is update your question with what you exactly want to match with some examples. Reading the comments your requirements change.

Comment: Sorry - I try to put the problem into pieces but I know for the readers it is not clear. So the /^[0-9]{5}(A?){3}$/ ist a good beginning but what I want to reach now is to mask the dot and/or a space between numbers and letters. e.g. It can be 20.555AA or 20555 AA or 20555AA but actually the right covention is 20555 AA. So I have to match all these and mask the dot but not the blank. But it can happen that is no blank as well...Is this clear? Tks a lot.